# Copy the collection and paste it to the same Database With Different Name on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Database {Databasename: Home} with 2 collections i.e

```
Home1 and Home2 //Two existing collection

Now I want to copy Home1 Table entirely and paste it on the same database with new name i.e Home3
```

Is it Possible to do on MongoDB. I am using Mongoose for my project.

And one more thing that is it possible to this job through Cron Job on Nodejs so that it will be a fully automated process.

Any help is really Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) (aggregation pipeline stage).

Example query:

```
db.getCollection('Home1').aggregate([{ $out : "Home3" }]);
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. You suggest the easiest approach. Is this process is reliable??

Answer (score 1):

You can copy documents from one collection to another, using collection method [copyTo()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/)

Using mongo shell command it would be like:
`db.yourCollectionName.copyTo("newCollection")`

And most probably the same syntax is used in mongoose as well